# Gpg-agent under Windows as SSH Agent for git bash

Tags: ssh, git, gnupg, gpg4win, gpg-agent

gpg-agent has options "--enable-ssh-support" and "--enable-putty-support" that allows it to use it as a drop-in replacement for the well-known ssh-agent.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how exactly make this work in windows and git-bash. (Please don't suggest me to use putty because I have lots of scripts and other programs that require being worked with git bash and openssh in my windows pc machine, including PHPStorm etc)

My first attempt was having `enable-ssh-support` line in `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\gpg-agent.conf` file,

And `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/c/users/[user]/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh` line in `/c/users/[user]/.bash_profile` file. (also I have created a windows environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` with the value `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\S.gpg-agent.ssh`)

I have my GPG Secret key in the key ring, with authentication and encryption enabled subkeys.

and I added keygrip of authentication enabled subkey into the `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\sshcontrol` file.

Since GnuPG 2.2.4 comes with [--export-ssh-key](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html) option so I don't need `monkeysphere` to convert the GPG key to OpenSSH format. so I exported my public key and I placed it in authorized_keys file in a remote Linux box with correct permissions (tested with another computer using putty).

Then I executed:
`gpg-connect-agent killagent /bye` and `gpg-connect-agent /bye` in PowerShell (and it started the gpg-agent running in background and created the `S.gpg-agent.ssh` SOCK file).

Then attempted to ssh into the server as the regular way.

And it gave me an error.

Then I tried enabling the putty support (`enable-putty-support` line in `gpg-agent.conf` allows you to enable putty support.

Also you need to create an enviornment variable in windows
`GIT_SSH='C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\PLINK.EXE'`)

Then I tried using OpenSSH that comes with chocolatey package manager too.

None of them worked as expected.

finally, I gave up on everything and attempted to connect just using putty and gpg-agent. I uninstalled git-bash too. Then I just attempted using GnuPG and Putty.

I allowed agent forwarding in putty ssh -> auth. then I tried to connect to the server, but It still asking for the password. gpg-agent doesn't forward the key, but it detects the `gpg-agent` as `PAGEANT`

Event log in putty:

`2018-02-10 16:48:51    Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22
2018-02-10 16:48:51 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
2018-02-10 16:48:52 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
2018-02-10 16:48:52 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
2018-02-10 16:48:52 Using SSH protocol version 2
2018-02-10 16:48:52 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-dss/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Host key fingerprint is:
2018-02-10 16:48:53 ssh-ed25519 256 1f:7b:5d:c4:b4:ae:5d:81:72:da:1d:c8:b2:cc:67:7b
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2018-02-10 16:48:53 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2018-02-10 16:49:07 Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
2018-02-10 16:49:07 Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys`

Can you spot my problem?
In putty log

Comment: Hi Ron, maybe you should have divide this into multiple smaller problems. Are you still having the problem?

Comment: I suspect that the reason it doesn't work in git-bash is either due to how git-bash handles sockets, or how gpg-agent on Windows exposes that socket. However, I can confirm that it is possible (at least as of today, when I just tried it) to use gpg-agent with PuTTY at least. If you want to narrow the scope of your question I'm happy to provide the steps I used.

Comment: I am having almost the exact same problem, and I did almost the same thing as you. `gpg-connect-agent` works with `putty`, but it does not work on the command line with `ssh`. I set up the `gpg-agent.conf` like you did (but I don't know how to check if it properly applied after a restart. And I set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the output of `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket`. As I said `gpg-connect-agent` works great with putty but no luck with `ssh`/`git` both on `cmd` and git `bash` on windows. Am I missing something?

Comment: I solved my issue, see my new answer: https://superuser.com/a/1678544/182880

Answer (score 3):

Let's take it step by step.

**1.** `Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys`

This is blocking you right now. I assume that you the log reports pageant but you are actually running gpg-agent in the background. You may want to double check this before proceeding.

Let's make sure the gpg-agent has loaded the key you need for ssh authentication.

```
> gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.21
...

> gpg -k --with-keygrip
...
sub   rsa4096/0x0123456789ABCDEF 2018-01-01 [A] [expires: 2019-01-01]
      Keygrip = 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567
...

> gpg-connect-agent "keyinfo --list" /bye
...
S KEYINFO 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567 T xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx OPENPGP.3 - - - - -
...
OK
```

This way you can confirm that your gpg-agent has the key you are expecting loaded. Next step would be to make sure server is requesting proper key.

**2.** TBA

Answer (score 0):

You want to use https://github.com/rupor-github/win-gpg-agent

After installing that, without changing any settings, I was able to successfully call `ssh -o IdentityAgent=\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent -v USER@IP`. Even just simply `ssh USER@IP` works now. And `git` with `SSH` with the key from a smartcard works well too.

The other Windows version https://www.gpg4win.org/ has broken `enable-ssh-support`
and the project seems in no rush to fix it: [Ticket 1](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3883), [Ticket 2](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4979), [Forum Post](https://wald.intevation.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=2359&forum_id=21&group_id=11) and [PowerShell github Thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/827)